# Decap cms admin panel not switching between collections

Tags: netlify-cms, decap-cms

I have a netlify website with Decap (former Netlify cms). I have set up 3 collections so that user can add different blog posts. When I go to /admin, I see all collections are visible, however, when I click on a specific collection, no matter which one, always all blog posts are shown. I would assume the collections would be sort of a filter.

Is there any kind of way to configure this?

collections:

- name: "fibrafort_boten"
  label: "Fibrafort boten"
  folder: "src/content/blog"
  create: true
  slug: "{{title}}"
  sortable_fields: ["tags", "title"]
- name: "tweedehands_boten"
  label: "Tweedehands boten"
  folder: "src/content/blog"
  create: true
  slug: "{{title}}"
  sortable_fields: ["tags", "title"]
  fields:

  - { label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string" }
  - { label: "Description", name: "description", widget: "string" }
  - {
- name: "tohatsu"
  label: "Tohatsu"
  folder: "src/content/blog"
  create: true
  slug: "{{title}}"
  sortable_fields: ["tags", "title"]
  fields:

  - { label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string" }
  - { label: "Description", name: "description", widget: "string" }
  - { label: "Tags", name: "tags", widget: "list", default: ["motoren"] }
  - { label: "Available", name: "status", widget: "boolean", default: true }
  - { label: "Price", name: "price", widget: "string" }
  - { label: "Featured Image", name: "image", widget: "image" }
  - { label: "Image Caption", name: "imageAlt", widget: "string" }

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out , will leave it here. it was because of     `folder: "src/content/blog"`  . All collections were in the same folder and thats why it was not switching between the posts in the Admin UI

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).